# Consume C++ COM class from Python

Tags: python, c++, com, atl

I have a COM dll which is created using ATL COM with C++. I am creating an Python application which can reuse the existing business logic written in COM C++.

I am looking for a way to consume the COM class object methods from the COM DLL from python. Please suggest ways to achieve this.

Comment: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pythoncom.html